# What is the reason for the following output in C get changed dynamically

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code segment I am dealing with. It outputs `500`, but I can not figure out, why this is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *f(int x){
    int p;
    p = x;
    printf("p is : %d\n",p);
    return &p;
}

int *g(int x){
    int y;
    y = x;
    printf("p is : %d\n",y);
    return &y;
}

int main(){
    int *x,*y;
    x = f(1000);
    y = g(250);
    *x = *x +250;
    printf("%d %d\n",*x,*y);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for the output of `500`?

Comment: You're using an address of a variable that has gone out of scope.

Comment: Doesn't our compiler warn you about returning stack pointers?

Comment: @Blaze the program is not returning stack pointers, it's returning pointers to local variables.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: The applicable concept is lifetime or storage duration, not scope.

Comment: I've closed as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). Although this question is about C++ the problem is _exactly the same_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your function:

```
int *f(int x){
    int p; 
    p = x;
    printf("p is : %d\n",p);
    return &p;
}
```

> **warning**: address of local variable 'p' returned
>   [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Here variable `p` is created in the scope of `f()`  after the return of function call this functions stack frame get destroyed so are everything in it, thus unexpected results. 
You can either return the  value directly or dynamically allocate memory using `malloc()`, in this case variable will be stored in heap instead of `f()` or particular functions stack later on you can free the memory when you're done.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning the address of a local variable.

The lifetime of the variables `p` and `y` in the functions `f` and `g` ends when those functions return.  As a result, the pointers to them become invalid and attempting to dereference them results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Rather than returning pointers, just return the value directly.